# How to count objects in list by properties?

Tags: c#, json, linq, count, deserialization

I deserialize a JSON like: `files = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Files>(json);`

I would like to count the *natives-windows* and *artifact*, so I used lamba, but I get NullReferenceException.

```
files.libraries.GroupBy(x => new { x.downloads.artifact, x.downloads.classifiers.natives-windows }).Count();
```

There are my classes:

```
public class Files
{
    public List<Library> libraries { get; set; }
}
public class Library
{
    public Downloads downloads { get; set; }
}
public class Downloads
{
    public Artifact artifact { get; set; }
    public Classifiers classifiers { get; set; }
}

public class Artifact{...}

public class Classifiers
{
    public NativesWindows natives-windows { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class NativesWindows{...}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a sample JSON payload and the result you are expecting (based on that JSON payload) and why.

Comment: @mjwills I would like to count how many `artifact` and `natives-windows` have been desirialized to `files` for my ProgressBar so I need to get a number of these objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is mismatch between your json data and your classes so that the returning object has null values.

Also I believe that your LINQ query has problems as well.

Try in this way. You need select after group by

```
files.libraries.GroupBy(x => new { x.downloads.artifact, 
     x.downloads?.classifiers?.natives-windows ?? "default value for nulls" })
     .Select(x => new { 
          Artifact = x.Key.artifact,
          NativesWindows = x.Key.natives-windows,
          Count = x.Count()
     });
```

Please keep in mind that fixing LINQ query will not solve your NullReferenceException

Comment: Thanks, _it can works if you close at end_. My problem is that, in the JSON payload somewhere/in some cases the `downloads` is contain the `classifiers` but not largely. I think it is the reason why I get NullReferenceException _(classifiers.get returned null)_.

Comment: you can use null propogation

Comment: check my answer